# Can a gun scavenger misfire with a Pistol of the Infinite Sky?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, class-feature, archetype, firearms

The [gun scavenger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger/archetypes/paizo-gunslinger-archetypes/gun-scavenger-gunslinger-archetype/) is a gunslinger archetype with high-risk-high-reward mechanics that increase misfire chances in exchange of great benefits :

> ***Go By Feel (Ex)***
>
> A gun scavenger’s intuitive and unique style leaves her firearms prone
>   to misfire, whether as a result of using too much powder, using
>   imperfectly milled parts, or any number of other minor
>   inconsistencies. **When using a firearm, a gun scavenger cannot reduce
>   that firearm’s misfire chance to 0; it can always misfire on a natural
>   1.**
>
> ***Deeds***
>
> A gun scavenger gains the following deeds at the listed level.
>
> ***Change Out (Ex)*** At 1st level, as a full-round action, a gun scavenger
>   can remove the broken condition from a single firearm she is currently
>   wielding, as long as that condition was gained by a firearm misfire.
>   When she does, she can replace the broken part with a specialized,
>   short-lived component that does one of the following: gives the
>   firearm the scatter weapon quality; increases the damage dealt by the
>   pistol-whip deed by one die size; or increases the firearm’s range
>   increment by 10 feet. **A firearm with such a modification increases its
>   misfire chance cumulatively by 1 each time it is fired until it
>   misfires. When it does misfire, the effects of the temporary component
>   are lost.** A gun scavenger must have at least 1 grit point to perform
>   this deed. **Alternatively, if the gun scavenger spends 1 grit point to
>   perform a change out, she can either perform the change out as a
>   standard action instead of a full-round action, or perform the change
>   out on a firearm that isn’t broken.**

I plan to get a [Pistol of the Infinite Sky](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/pistol-of-the-infinite-sky/) when the party's magic item crafter can possibly make one :

> This pistol never needs to be reloaded. After one shot is fired, a
>   bullet and powder magically appear in the chamber. **This ammunition
>   never suffers a misfire.**

Then what happens if a gun scavenger rolls a natural 1 when using a Pistol of the Infinite Sky or tries to modify it with Change Out ?

Comment: Maybe write your own thoughts as an answer, rather than a comment, or edit them into the question if that is more appropriate. Comments should be transitory.

Answer (score 5):

Given a strict RAW reading, you can use change out as you wish with the Pistol of the Infinite Sky without any misfire chance.

---

Reasoning:

The Pistol doesn't say that the misfire value is reduced to zero. Since the misfire value isn't reduced by any means, *Go By Feel* can't be called upon to increase the misfire. As far as we can tell, the Pistol has a misfire value normal for a gun of its type, the ammunition can simply never *suffer* a misfire. As such, even increasing the misfire value with *Change Out* would not affect the Pistol of the Infinite Sky- the misfire value may be whatever, but the ammunition inside never suffers a misfire.

The situation is akin to a Paladin with Aura of Courage (thus immune to fear) suffering a -4 penalty vs fear saves; technically he takes the -4 to the save, but he's immune to the effect. The gun is suffering a higher chance to fail, but is immune to the failure.

---

However, this GM would say a reading that pedantic, removing all risk from an archetype and acquiring free buffs is dumb, and would probably make a halfway ruling. This GM would probably allow the pistol to have a 0 misfire despite the *Go By Feel* ability, but impose the normal extra misfire chance with *Change Out*.

Comment: I must admit I don't see the difference between "reduce the misfire value to 0" and "can't suffer a misfire". If it was a MtG card ruling I guess your reasoning would apply, but given the context it seems wrong.

Comment: @AnneAunyme if you reduce the misfire to 0, it *can* have misfires, it just happens that the value is impossible to reach by normal methods, and it explicitly triggers the *Go By Feel* ability. If it can "never misfire" it has no misfire value- it hasn't been reduced to 0, it explicitly *doesn't have* a misfire value. More mathematically, misfires trigger when `r <= m`, where *r* is 'roll' and *m* is 'misfire'; in normal cases you can modify *m* with addition/subtraction. However, for the *Pistol*, *m* is negative infinity. Normal operations are useless, and you can never be `<=` to it.

Comment: So you can have misfire, but only if you roll a 0 on a D20? This seems pretty close to "never misfire" to me. Can you give as a reference any tangible example on which *Go By Feel* would trigger?

Comment: @AnneAunyme Go By Feel would trigger anytime you would reduce the misfire roll to 0. For example, the [Reliable](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/reliable/) weapon enchantment reduces the misfire chance by 1. A +1 Reliable Pistol (default misfire: 1) would have its misfire value reduced by 1 to 0. However, the gunslinger can never reduce the misfire to 0 due to their Go By Feel ability, and the misfire would still be 1.

Answer (score 3):

The rules contradict each other and do not share a scope.  You must ask your GM to resolve the inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

The more specific (here the *Go By Feel* class ability) applies: a misfire happens when a gun scavenger rolls a natural 1 when using a Pistol of the Infinite Sky.

You can sum up the rules as such:

- standard rule: on a 1 on an attack roll, a misfire happens.
- weapon property of the Pistol: this firearm doesn't provoke misfires.
- Go By Feel: you can't cancel the misfire on a 1.

Here the class ability is more specific, not because it is a class ability but because it is a rule made to counter other rules that would modify the basic case.

You can compare that to the case of Paladin's aura of courage and Antipaladin's aura of cowardice:

- standard rule: people are not naturally immune to fear
- aura of courage: makes the Paladin immune to fear
- aura of cowardice: creatures immune to fear lose their immunity

Result: the Paladin is not immune to fear when in the aura of cowardice.

Comment: Why is the class ability (which applies all the time) *more* specific than the weapon special ability (which applies only when using that weapon)? (I mean, so far as I know there's no *formal* way to determine specificity; I'm just curious about the reasoning here.)

Comment: Both the class feature and the rules for the pistol are "made to counter other rules." I am not clear on your reasoning here.

Comment: The rule on the weapon is made to counter the standard rule (that on a 1 a misfire happens) and the class feature is made to counter rules that would counter the standard one. Added a parallel example

Comment: Frankly, there is no precedence for your answer. Given equally-specific things (two class abilities), order of application is GM call unless you can find a source for your claim.

Comment: @Delioth: so you mean the Antipaladin aura of cowardice shouldn't trump the Paladin's aura of courage? In this case what is actually the use of aura of cowardice?